# live table delete button when another button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery and I'm trying to delete a button called "DELETE" when another button, called "EDIT", is clicked.
I don't know how to deal with this problem, I searched in StackOverflow, but I found only to change buttons in static tables, not in a dynamic like this.
Here is the code:

**PHP table**

```
<table>
    <tr>
     <th>Nome</th>
     <th>Cognome</th>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Password</th>
     <th>Azioni</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr data-row='{$row['iduser']}'>";
        echo "<td data-column='name'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
              <td data-column='surname'>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>
              <td data-column='username'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
              <td data-column='email'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
              <td data-column='password'>" . $row['password'] . "</td>
              <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>EDIT</button>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-delete'>DELETE</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>

</table>
```

**JQuery "EDIT" function**

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on("click", ".btn-info", function(){

        $(".btn-delete").remove();

        var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
        var id = $(parent).attr("data-row");

        var name = $(parent).children("[data-column='name']");
        var surname = $(parent).children("[data-column='surname']");
        var username = $(parent).children("[data-column='username']");
        var email = $(parent).children("[data-column='email']");
        var password = $(parent).children("[data-column='password']");

        var nameTxt = $(name).html();
        var surnameTxt = $(surname).html();
        var usernameTxt = $(username).html();
        var emailTxt = $(email).html();
        var passwordTxt = $(password).html();


        $(name).html("<input name='name' data-dc='name' value='" + nameTxt + "'>");
        $(surname).html("<input name='surname' data-dc='surname' value='" + surnameTxt + "'>");
        $(username).html("<input name='username' data-dc='username' value='" + usernameTxt + "'>");
        $(email).html("<input name='email' data-dc='email' value='" + emailTxt + "'>");
        $(password).val('').html("<input name='password' data-dc='password' value='" + passwordTxt + "'>");

        $("[data-dc='password']").val('');
    });
});
```

With "**$(".btn-delete").remove()**" it removes every **"DELETE"** button inside live table.
I need to understand how to make a working function to delete the button **"DELETE"** in the same **row** of button **"EDIT"**
Sorry for my English, hope to get understood. Tell me if must be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the next delete button try to use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next),

```
$(this).next(".btn-delete").remove();
```

or you can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) like

```
$(this).closest('td').find(".btn-delete").remove();
```

And if you have `parent` then use it directly like,

```
parent.find(".btn-delete").remove();
```

Also, you can use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to short your code like,

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-info", function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    parent.find(".btn-delete").remove();

    var id = $(parent).attr("data-row");
    //var name = $(parent).children("[data-column='name']");
    //var surname = $(parent).children("[data-column='surname']");
    //var username = $(parent).children("[data-column='username']");
    //var email = $(parent).children("[data-column='email']");
    //var password = $(parent).children("[data-column='password']");

    //var nameTxt = $(name).html();
    //var surnameTxt = $(surname).html();
    //var usernameTxt = $(username).html();
    //var emailTxt = $(email).html();
    //var passwordTxt = $(password).html();


    // use html callback
    name.html(function(){
         return "<input name='name' data-dc='name' value='" + $(this).text() + "'>"
    });
    surname.html(function(){
         return "<input name='surname' data-dc='surname' value='" + $(this).text() + "'>"
    });
    username.html(function(){
         return "<input name='username' data-dc='username' value='" + $(this).text() + "'>"
    });
    email.html(function(){
         return "<input name='email' data-dc='email' value='" + $(this).text() + "'>"
    });
    password.html(function(){
         return "<input name='password' data-dc='password' value=''>"
    });
});
```

Alternatively a better way is,

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-info", function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    parent.find(".btn-delete").remove();

    var id = $(parent).attr("data-row");
    $('[data-column]').each(function(){
       var self = $(this);
       self.html(function(){
          key = self.attr('data-column');
             return "<input name='"+key+"' data-dc='"+key+"' value='"+self.text()+"'>"
       });
    });
    // need to blank password field here,
    parent.find("[data-dc='password']").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are already  targeting the parent `TR` element, use it as context

```
$(".btn-delete", parent).remove();
//parent.find(".btn-delete").remove();
```